# Detect Floating point input using javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find whether a number inputed by a user is valid
Following cases are valid

```
 1. `12`  

 2. `12.01`
```

The following case is invalid:

```
1. `12.`  // decimal point with no number following
```

I have written a regular expression like

```
var decimalValidation = /^[0-9]*(\.?)[0-9]*$/;  
var n = decimalValidation .test(value);
```

But the problem is that it accepts a value like `12.`

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex like below to match both integer and floating point numbers.

```
var decimalValidation = /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/;
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eW8zY6/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If this was the case, I would use the following as pattern:

```
var pattern = /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

I hope this fits in your condition.